# Place RadioButtonList in a table column

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ado

I dynamically create my labels and Radio Button Lists in my web forms asp.net application. Afterwards, I place them in a table.
I am having a problem with displaying the actual radio button list control in the table.

How do I display the control instead of the Text being shown?
The code I have is:

```html
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineCheckListConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetApplications", con))
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "rbrown");

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string tablestring = "<table border = \"1\" CssClass=\"TestClass\">" +
                        "<tr><td>First Column Heading</td><td>second Column</td></tr>";
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {                
                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        RadioButtonList c = new RadioButtonList();

                        lbl.ID = "Label" + i.ToString();
                        c.ID = "cbl" + i.ToString();

                        lbl.Text += dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "<br/>";
                        c.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yes"));
                        c.Items.Add(new ListItem("NO"));

                        c.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
                        //this.Controls.Add(lbl);
                        //this.Form.Controls.Add(c);
                        tablestring = tablestring + "<tr><td>" + lbl.Text.ToString() + "</td><td>" + c + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    divTable.InnerHtml = tablestring;
```

[image: Image showing the current result of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest you to use `AspGridView`, not plain HTML table.
You could use `<ItemTemplate>` and `<EditItemTemplate>` to add `RadioButtonList` in aspx.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" DataKeyNames="OrderId" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowEditing="EditCustomer" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="UpdateCustomer"
    CssClass="Grid" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Customer Name" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipCity" HeaderText="Ship City" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipper">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblShipper" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblShipper" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShipperId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblShippers" runat="server">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then fill the data through `RowDataBound`

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvOrders.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        RadioButtonList rblShippers = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rblShippers");
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Shippers";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        rblShippers.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        rblShippers.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
        rblShippers.DataValueField = "ShipperId";
        rblShippers.DataBind();
        rblShippers.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblShipper") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the demo:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/406/default.aspx

And Complete Example:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-and-save-ASPNet-RadioButtonList-with-Selected-Value-in-Edit-ItemTemplate-of-GridView.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `RadioButtonList` is a `WebControl`, that can be used inside another `WebControl`. In your code you are creating a table by concatenating HTML text, therefore, outside the domain of the Web Forms view state model.

When you are concatenating `c` in your HTML text variable, you are just getting the value returned by `c.ToString()`, which by default is the full name of the type.

Having said that, please use the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table` type to build your table instead, and add the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList` to it; I'm leaving a basic example below that you can use as a starting point:

In your aspx file (somewhere inside your form element):

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="myTable"></asp:Table>
```

In your code-behind file:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

...

void SomeMethod()
{
    var row = new TableRow();

    var cell = new TableCell();

    var radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
    radioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yes"));
    radioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("NO"));

    cell.Controls.Add(radioButtonList);

    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    myTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```